# Best way to display floating action button on top of another one

Tags: android, android-layout

What if I want to display a smaller floating action button on top of another one? Using a ConstraintLayout is the obvious way, but is it possible to do it in LinearLayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an edge case but you can achieve it with this hack.

```
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"/>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-60dp" />  //Here is some hack.
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

I get this result in this code. These both are the floating action button those float together.